# find $f'(x)$ for $f(x)= \frac{x+5}{x+3}$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Find $f'(x)$ for $f(x)=\frac{x+5}{x+3}$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2 +1}$ and determine all values $c$ where $f'(c)=0$.

I used the quotient rule to find the derivatives. Then I let it to be equal to $0$.

For the first one, I get $$f'(x)=-\frac{2}{(x+3)^2}$$ and when I let it equal to $0$, I get -2/0 for x=-3. but this is not defined

I am stuck with second equation as I get $$f'(x)=-\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

Comment: What answers did you get? If you post your working, we can verify whether it's right or not, and help you if we spot any errors.

Comment: for the first one i get f'(x)=-2/(x+3)^2 and when i let it egual to 0 i get -3

Comment: i am stuck with second equation as i get f'(x)=-2x/(x^2+1)^2

Comment: is this right so?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  In future, please include your attempt in your question and explain where you are stuck so that you receive feedback that addresses the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Both the first function and its derivative are undefined when $x = -3$.  The derivative does not have a zero.

Comment: I'm curious how exactly did you get $-3$ for the first derivative and couldn't solve the other one. There is some misunderstanding going on in how equations are solved.

Answer (score 1):

for $$f(x)=\frac{x+5}{x+4}$$ we obtain by the Quotient rule
$$f'(x)=\frac{x+3-(x+5)}{(x+3)^2}$$
simplifying we obtain $$f'(x)=-\frac{2}{(x+3)^2}$$
this can not be Zero for any $x$
for the second we get $$f'(x)=\frac{-2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$$ and $f'(x)=0$ if $x=0$

Comment: for the second  i obtained x=0

Comment: @M.elena  That is correct.

Comment: i have added the solution in my post

Answer (score 0):

For the first we have $$\left(1+\frac{2}{x+3}\right)'=-\frac{2}{(x+3)^2}\neq0$$  and for the second, which was  $1+\frac{1}{x^2}$it's also impossible.

If you mean the the second is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ then we get $-\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2},$ which gives $c=0$.

Comment: What is impossible with the second function?

Comment: i obtained x=0 is this right?